# Why does my unit test pass when verifying signed metadata, but fails when signing through Polkadot.js

Tags: pallet, signing

I have function that will take an admin account and verify when metadata is passed in that the admin account has signed it and the Signature is provided in a struct called `NftSaleMetadata<AccountId, BoundedString>`. When I write unit tests the tests pass, but when I write the javascript scripts to sign the metadata then execute a transaction, I get failures. Is there something wrong with my verification function?

`NftSaleMetadata` struct

```
/// Metadata to ensure metadata passed in is signed by the Overlord account
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Debug, PartialEq, TypeInfo)]
pub struct NftSaleMetadata<BoundedString> {
    pub metadata: BoundedString,
    pub signature: sr25519::Signature,
}
```

`verify_nft_metadata` that is called from a public minting function

```
pub fn verify_nft_metadata(
    overlord: &T::AccountId,
    nft_metadata: NftSaleMetadata<BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>>,
) -> Result<BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>, Error<T>> {
    let metadata = nft_metadata.metadata;
    let signature = nft_metadata.signature;
    // Serialize evidence
    let msg = Encode::encode(&metadata);
    let encode_overlord = T::AccountId::encode(overlord);
    let h256_overlord = H256::from_slice(&encode_overlord);
    let overlord_key = sr25519::Public::from_h256(h256_overlord);
    // verify claim
    ensure!(
        sp_io::crypto::sr25519_verify(&signature, &msg, &overlord_key),
        Error::<T>::InvalidMetadata
    );
    Ok(metadata)
}
```

Unit test example that passes where `claim_spirit` will call helper function `verify_nft_metadata` to verify the signed metadata

```
#[test]
fn claimed_spirit_works() {
    ExtBuilder::default().build(OVERLORD).execute_with(|| {
        let overlord_pair = sr25519::Pair::from_seed(b"28133080042813308004281330800428");
        // let overlord_pub = overlord_pair.public();
        // Set Overlord and configuration then enable spirits to be claimed
        setup_config(StatusType::ClaimSpirits);
        let metadata = stb("I am Spirit");
        let enc_metadata = Encode::encode(&metadata);
        let metadata_signature = overlord_pair.sign(&enc_metadata);
        let nft_sale_metadata =
            NftSaleMetadata { metadata: metadata.clone(), signature: metadata_signature };
        // Sign BOB's Public Key and Metadata encoding with OVERLORD account
        let claim = Encode::encode(&BOB);
        let overlord_signature = overlord_pair.sign(&claim);
        let bob_ticket = ClaimSpiritTicket { account: BOB, signature: overlord_signature };
        // Dispatch a claim spirit from BOB's account
        assert_ok!(PhalaWorld::claim_spirit(
            Origin::signed(BOB),
            Some(bob_ticket),
            nft_sale_metadata.clone()
        ));
        // ALICE should be able to claim since she has minimum amount of PHA
        assert_ok!(PhalaWorld::claim_spirit(Origin::signed(ALICE), None, nft_sale_metadata));
    });
}
```

JS script that fail when trying to `claim_spirit` the output to console says valid signature, but the transaction fails with invalid metadata

```
const keyring = new Keyring({type: 'sr25519'});
// status types
const claimSpirits = api.createType('StatusType', 'ClaimSpirits');
const overlord = keyring.addFromUri(overlordPrivkey);
const metadata = stringToU8a('I am Spirit');
const metadataSig = overlord.sign(metadata);
const isValid = overlord.verify(metadata, metadataSig, overlord.publicKey);
    
// output the result
console.log(`${u8aToHex(metadataSig)}\n ${u8aToHex(metadata)} is ${isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}`);
const nftSignedMetadata = api.createType("NftSaleMetadata", {'metadata': metadata, 'signature': metadataSig});
await api.tx.phalaWorld.claimSpirit(null, nftSignedMetadata).signAndSend(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up resolving the issue. What the substrate code is doing is encoding the metadata before signing with the `Overlord` admin account which is a step I was missing with my JS script. Here is what the script looks like that allowed to verify the signed metadata.

```
const metadata = 'I am Spirit';
const metadataType = api.createType('BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>', metadata).toU8a();
const metadataSig = overlord.sign(metadataType);
const isValid = overlord.verify(metadata, metadataSig, overlord.address);
const nftSignedMetadata = api.createType('NftSaleMetadata', {'metadata': metadataType, 'signature': metadataSig});
    
  
// Mint a Spirit with another user account
await api.tx.phalaWorld.claimSpirit(null, nftSignedMetadata).signAndSend(user);
```